# How to add dependency to module's list of dependencies in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [angular-bootstrap-nav-tree](https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree) library, but I'cant add 'angularBootstrapNavTree' to my module's list of dependencies. There is error 
`"Unknown provider: angularBootstrapNavTreeProvider <- angularBootstrapNavTree"`

```
 angular.
  module('myApp').
  component('treeList', {
      template: ' <abn-tree tree-data="my_data"></abn-tree>',
      controller: function MyCtrl($http, $scope, dataContext, angularBootstrapNavTree) {              
          $scope.my_data = [{
              label: 'Languages',
              children: ['Jade','Less','Coffeescript'],
              classes: ["special", "red"]
          }]      
     });
```

Comment: Have you included the following files properly ?
**abn_tree_directive.js**,
**abn_tree.css**

Comment: @Korte , yes, I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a `;` and a `}` in your synthax, I fixed it:

```
angular.
  module('myApp').
  component('treeList', {
      template: '<abn-tree tree-data="my_data"></abn-tree>',
      controller: function MyCtrl($http, $scope, dataContext, angularBootstrapNavTree) {              
          $scope.my_data = [{
              label: 'Languages',
              children: ['Jade','Less','Coffeescript'],
              classes: ["special", "red"]
          }];      
      } 
   });
```

Furthermore, you may have forgot to add `angularBootstrapNavTree` to your module dependencies:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularBootstrapNavTree']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have actually to add it to your **module's list of dependencies**, not in controller's dependencies.

```
angular.module('myApp',['angularBootstrapNavTree'])
```